# How can I print a txt file content with utf-8 characters in Python?

Tags: python

When I'm trying to print from a file, I get:
io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable

How can I print the file content?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask], and [try to](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) research questions before asking, for example by [copying and pasting the error message into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=io.UnsupportedOperation%3A+not+readable).